# What does this snippet in HTTP JSON API SERVER excercise in learnyounode

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, http

#### Context

I've come across excercise in *learnyounode*

```
npm install -g learnyounode
```

called HTTP JSON API SERVER. 
Goal of an excercise:

> Write an HTTP server that serves JSON data when it receives a GET request to the path '/api/parsetime'. Expect the request to contain a
>   query string with a key 'iso' and an ISO-format time as the value.
>
> For example:
>
> /api/parsetime?iso=2013-08-10T12:10:15.474Z

I wasn't able to solve it, which I think is due to lack of some specific API knowledge, so i looked up a solution, and found this (which works fine btw):

```js
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

    function parsetime (time) {
      return {
        hour: time.getHours(),
        minute: time.getMinutes(),
        second: time.getSeconds()
      };
    }

    function unixtime (time) {
      return { unixtime : time.getTime() };
    }

    var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      var parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
      var time = new Date(parsedUrl.query.iso);
      var result;

      if (/^\/api\/parsetime/.test(req.url))
        result = parsetime(time);
      else if (/^\/api\/unixtime/.test(req.url))
        result = unixtime(time);

      if (result) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
      } else {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();
      }
    })
    
    server.listen(Number(process.argv[2]));
```

### Actual question

I looked at this snippet and froze.

```
if (/^\/api\/parsetime/.test(req.url))
        result = parsetime(time);
else if (/^\/api\/unixtime/.test(req.url))
        result = unixtime(time);
```

Could anyone explain what `/^\/api\/parsetime/.test(req.url)` does exactly? At first it looks like some kind of regular expression, but I've never seen that RegExp could invoke methods. I guess that it is some form of identifying URL path, but guess is not worth much in industry.

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: Yep, it's for identifying the URL path [RegExp.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may look as if

```
if (/^\/api\/parsetime/.test(req.url))
    result = parsetime(time);
else if (/^\/api\/unixtime/.test(req.url))
    result = unixtime(time);
```

is invoking a function, but it is just generating a string output which the actual invoker called .test() turns into a truthful expression.

For more on javascript regex have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

The instructions say :

> Write an HTTP server that serves JSON data when it receives a GET request to the path '/api/parsetime' (...) add second endpoint to the path '/api/unixtime'

which means the GET requests the server gets can be to paths other than '/api/parsetime' (resp. '/api/unixtime')

So, you want to test whether the GET request the server gets is to either of the 2 paths mentioned. And you do that with a regexp. An easy way to check the URL against the 2 URL given, is to use the test() method.

See examples of regexp on MDN :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
if (/^\/api\/parsetime/.test(req.url))
    result = parsetime(time);
else if (/^\/api\/unixtime/.test(req.url))
    result = unixtime(time)
```

The first "`/`" character in the if statement denotes the beginning of a regex object in JavaScript and it is ended with another "`/`" character. So `/a/.test('a')` for example would evaluate to `true`.

The "`^`" character in a regex just denotes the first character in a regex and the "`\/`" is because the "`/`" is a special character that ends the regex, and the "`\`" in front is another special character that cancels out special characters, so with "`\/`" we end up with a literal "`/`"  as the first("`^`") character in our search pattern.

So in the regex above `/^\/api\/parsetime/` we keep the pattern going by canceling out the "`/`" characters. The "`^`" goes in front to say we need to start with a literal "`/`". And then we terminate the regex as always with "`/`".

Regular Expressions and other special characters found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score -1):

```
var http = require('http')
var url = require('url')

function parsetime (time) {
  return {
    hour: time.getHours(),
    minute: time.getMinutes(),
    second: time.getSeconds()
  }
}

function unixtime (time) {
  return { unixtime: time.getTime() }
}

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true)
  var time = new Date(parsedUrl.query.iso)
  var result

  if (/^\/api\/parsetime/.test(req.url)) {
    result = parsetime(time)
  } else if (/^\/api\/unixtime/.test(req.url)) {
    result = unixtime(time)
  }

  if (result) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    res.end(JSON.stringify(result))
  } else {
    res.writeHead(404)
    res.end()
  }
})
server.listen(Number(process.argv[2]))
```